# How to detect the direction that looks to player - Java

Tags: java, animation, angle, direction

Hello I am making a game for tests in Java and I want to make something but don't know how.
So I have 4 animations for directions up/down/left/right and position of the animal (entity) and player.

I want to make the animal look towards player all time but don't know how to make it. If I use  'if entity.x>player.x' it will look to the correct side but wont be able to look down or up?

Hopefully you understeand what I mean, please answer :D

Comment: *"Please if you know something tell me."* I know it makes sense to ask a question.  What is your question?  Also.. *"I tried using the angle to determine which animation should run but failed"* Try describing what you did (your best attempt) in an SSCCE.  Code speaks louder than words.

Comment: Ok, I know how you feel because I often see people say a question like me but I don't know how to explain it better. I have 4 animations for up/down/left/right for an entity (mob) and I want the entity to look at the player all the time. I don't know how to detect the direction that looks to player.

Comment: Pointed hint "How to detect the direction that looks to player?" is not only a question, but the first question appearing on this page.  Please edit it into the post so I can delete some noise.

Comment: Also describe what you mean by 4 animations for 4 directions, is it N-W-S-E or facing,against,left side, right side etc

Comment: Okay, edited the question. I think it's better now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're half way there already. What you want to do is determine where in relation to the animal the player lies.

Let's first make an enum to encapsulate this

```
enum Direction { NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST };
```

As you said, you can check whether the player is on the left or right of the animal.

```
if(player.getX() > animal.getX()) {
    animal.setDirection(Direction.EAST);
} else { 
    animal.setDirection(Direction.WEST);
}
```

likewise, you can do the same thing with Y coordinates and the North/South direction.

```
if(player.getY() > animal.getY()) {
    animal.setDirection(Direction.NORTH);
} else { 
    animal.setDirection(Direction.SOUTH);
}
```

So now, how do we figure out whether we should use the first check or the second check? Well, think about it for a second. If you live "north" of where you are, you probably aren't straight north, but rather, mostly north - certainly, more north than east, for example. So a good check is then, "what is the dominant direction" - ie. if you live further north than you are east, you say you live north. So how do you check that? Well, you say that the distance you must travel North/South to your place is greater than the distance you must travel East/West. In code:

```
if(Math.abs(animal.getX() - player.getX()) > Math.abs(animal.getY() - player.getY())) {
    //More east-west than north-south - do EAST-WEST check
} else {
    //More north-south than east-west - do NORTH-SOUTH check
}
```

So, combining this gives the final result:

```
if(Math.abs(animal.getX() - player.getX()) > Math.abs(animal.getY() - player.getY())) {
    //More east-west than north-south - do EAST-WEST check
    if(player.getX() > animal.getX()) {
        animal.setDirection(Direction.EAST);
    } else { 
        animal.setDirection(Direction.WEST);
    }
} else {
     //More north-south than east-west - do NORTH-SOUTH check
    if(player.getY() > animal.getY()) {
        animal.setDirection(Direction.NORTH);
    } else { 
        animal.setDirection(Direction.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

And you are done! Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot I was thinking of doing something like this but wasn't sure how because I didn't know about the Math.abs.